# How to respond to URL requests with an action in c#

Tags: c#, httplistener

What I am essentially trying to do, is to listen to certain http requests and doing different actions based on them. For example, if I open `http://localhost:8080/test` in my browser, I would like to perform an action that corresponds to test. I know that this can be done with httplistener, but exactly how it is done I cannot figure out.

Comment: You are describing exactly what ASP.NET MVC does.  Of course, that requires a web server; if you need something lighter, Node.js might be your speed.

Answer (score 3):

Just use the [HttpListenerRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httplistenerrequest.aspx) object to get the URL and perform whatever action you would like to perform.

Edit: Removed invalid link.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is an implementation of `ASP.NET Routing`.
This is the most efficient way to do this, and you can [read more here.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)